# how to know if a function of syslog called successfully?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

with command `man 3 syslog` in linux command line, we can see functions introduction as follow:

```
void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
void closelog(void);
```

we can find that the return value of these functions are 'void', so
how to know if a function like "syslog(...)" is called successfully?
if you stop rsyslog service on centos, you can also run the following program without error:

```
#include <syslog.h>   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{   
    openlog("testsyslog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL3);   
    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_INFO, "syslog test message generated in program %s(=======from test!) \n", argv[0]);   
    closelog();   
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: use `perror()`. `perror("syslog")`

Comment: but if I stop the service of rsyslog, I will get `success` from `perror`.

Answer (score 2):

As per the manual,

> The option argument to openlog() is an OR of any of these:
>
> LOG_CONS  Write directly to system console if there is an error while
>   sending to system logger.
>     ...

So, if you specify LOG_CONS and the output comes on the console, it implies that the message could not be logged in the syslog.

Comment: I know where the message logged, but I want to know if the message is trully logged in my codes. As I tried in my centos, I can not judge if the message logged through `errno` or `perror()`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know whether those syslog function calls are successful. The reason is a `syslog` call just sends a single network packet to the `syslogd` (or `rsyslogd` which is compatible with `syslogd`), which is both a Unix domain socket and a UDP socket server. There is no response from the `syslogd` daemon. So if there's failure like packet loss, you don't know. I believe this is by design to make the log mechanism as simple as possible to avoid unnecessary logging overhead.